# jQuery $(this).nextUntil('h3').toggle(); - hidden ul inside an ul

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm struggling for two days now on how to toggle specific content for my first project (started coding about a week ago, so I'm a newbie). I have searched other topics and read articles/done tutorials, and they helped me in the right direction, but I'm still not there yet. Who knows how to tackle this?

**Goal**:
Only the h3s should be visible when the page loads. When I click on h3, I want everything until the next h3 to toggle (thus, the ul and the 'sub' ul).

**Current situation**: List Items 1 and 2 toggle, but the Sublist items are not (they stay hidden).

```
<div>
<h3>Heading</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
      <ul>
       <li>Sublist item 1</li>
       <li>Sublist item 2</li>
      </ul>
    <li>List item 2</li>
      <ul>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
  </ul>
<h3>Next heading</h3>
...
</div>
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
   $('h3').click(function() {
     $(this).nextUntil('h3').toggle();
   });
 });
```

And the CSS that hides the ul when the page loads:

```
ul {
  display: none;
  visibility: inherit;
}
```

I think the problem is in my CSS (because List Item 2 does load), but after two days I'm still not able to fix it. Who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only hide the sibling `UL` of `h3`, so change the selector for CSS rules as

```
h3+ul {
  display: none;
  visibility: inherit;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('h3').click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('h3').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
h3+ul {
  display: none;
  visibility: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3>Heading</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Sublist item 1</li>
      <li>Sublist item 2</li>
    </ul>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <h3>Next heading</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>List item 4</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Sublist item 4</li>
      <li>Sublist item 4</li>
    </ul>

  </ul>
</div>
```

As pointed by @lonut, You should add nested `UL` as child of `LI`

Comment: Are those `ul` in `ul` valid `HTML` syntax? Shouldn't every inner `ul` be wrapped with a `<li></li>`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Please try this one.
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function() { 
   $('h3').click(function() {
     $(this).nextUntil('h3').toggle();
   });
 });
```

```css
ul {
  display: none;
  visibility: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<h3>Heading</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
      <ul>
       <li>Sublist item 1</li>
       <li>Sublist item 2</li>
      </ul>
    <li>List item 2</li>
      <ul>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
  </ul>
<h3>Next heading</h3>
<ul>
    <li>List item 3</li>
      <ul>
       <li>Sublist item 3</li>
       <li>Sublist item 4</li>
      </ul>
    <li>List item 4</li>
      <ul>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I already linked the latest version of jQuery (sorry, I should've mentioned this). Fortunately, its already resolved. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I have nothing changed in your code.just update the script reference only and it's working.

Comment: Oh that's strange! Hmm, maybe because of different browsers? The snippet also doesn't show the sublist. I'm using the exact same tag (within my head element, thats correct?).

Comment: Yup..First I have try your code on JSFiddle and then paste here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion :

1. add a class to the "main" `<ul>`s (for example : `section`), not on the sub elements :

   ```
   <div>
   <h3>First Heading</h3>
     <ul class="section">
       <li>List item 1</li>
         <ul>
          <li>Sublist item 1</li>
          <li>Sublist item 2</li>
         </ul>
       <li>List item 2</li>
         <ul>
           <li></li>
         </ul>
     </ul>
   <h3>Second heading</h3>
     <ul class="section">
       <li>List item 1</li>
         <ul>
          <li>Sublist item 1</li>
          <li>Sublist item 2</li>
         </ul>
       <li>List item 2</li>
         <ul>
           <li></li>
         </ul>
     </ul>
   <h3>Third heading</h3>
   ...
   </div>
   ```
2. apply your css hiding rule only on this class :

   ```
   ul.section {
       display: none;
   }
   ```
3. your javascript handler should work :

   ```
   $('h3').click(function() {
     $(this).nextUntil('h3').toggle();
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank! Thought of that too, but hoped there would be an easier solution (its a pretty extensive doc). Fortunately, there was - see answer above. But thank you for your reply!